# Update isn't taking all parameters from form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i submit my form, I have the following:

```
Started PATCH "/shop_products/12" 
---
INFO -- : [f51ce4b8-f181-4da5-919a-01c99c703762] Processing by ShopProductsController#update as HTML
---
INFO -- : [f51ce4b8-f181-4da5-919a-01c99c703762]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xkByz5wY7x9ZBEcGPawvrrlsDsDSThX3mEBl09qZU7x+OEHSRvryGV1tS520hGAL3bihE1C/c1xnIoDhzocRTw==", "shop_product"=>{"product_id"=>"1", "store_product_id"=>"1965852983345", "store_variant_id"=>"15345629364273", "shop_id"=>"1", "sync"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Sync", "id"=>"12"}
---
DEBUG -- : [f51ce4b8-f181-4da5-919a-01c99c703762]   [1m[36mShopProduct Load (1.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "shop_products".* FROM "shop_products" WHERE "shop_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
---
DEBUG -- : [f51ce4b8-f181-4da5-919a-01c99c703762]   [1m[36mShopProduct Load (3.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "shop_products".* FROM "shop_products" WHERE "shop_products"."store_variant_id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["store_variant_id", IS NULL LIMIT $1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
---
Completed 404 Not Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
---
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product without an ID):
```

Method:

```
def update
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.find_by(store_variant_id: params[:store_variant_id])
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop_product.update_attributes!(product_id: params[:product_id], sync: params[:sync])
        format.html { redirect_to @shop_product, notice: 'Shop product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shop_product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shop_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The form is coming from a separate controller so it's not coming directly from `edit/:id`.  The record is identified on the front-end from a loop/

```
<% @in_store_variants.each do |variant| %>
    <% if @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
      <% shop_product = @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
    <% end %>
<%= form_for shop_product do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :sku %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :store_product_id, value: variant.product_id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :store_variant_id, value: variant.id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :sync, value: true %>
   <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
<% end %>
.....
<% end %>
```

Question:

Why is the `product_id` not being passed to the update method in the controler controller when it's clearly being passed on from the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your product_id is in the params hash, but you have to access it like so:
`params["shop_product"]["product_id"]` because it is nested under shop_product. The form_for is nesting all the form inputs in the params hash under the key `"shop_product"`.

On a side note I would recommend you to work with strong params instead of passing the values from the params directly into your update method :)

Comment: Yes, I now have strong params in place.. Thank you so much.  If only i asked this question 12 hours ago lol.  Another quick Q if you can... How is ShopProduct being found in the `set_shop_product` method where it looks for the ID when I'm never passing the id?  I wonder because I changed the updated method to `@shop_product = ShopProduct.find(params[:id])` and it somehow finds the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, it can find it, because you're passing it via the url: `Started PATCH "/shop_products/12` The params hash also comes from the url and if you have a closer look at it, you can see the last key value pair is a `"id => 12` which stands for the shop_product_id in the url :)

Comment: Ends up being because i define it in the front end... which i am removing... I have the form on a separate view from a separate controller... I was all mixed up from the millions of attempts.  Also was first time using ruby 4 (from ruby 5).. 5 uses objects...